# Can grep | crontab destroy all jobs?

Tags: cron

My colleague ran `grep | crontab`. After that all jobs disappeared. Looks like he was trying to run `crontab -l`.

So what happened after running the command `grep | crontab`? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`crontab` can install new `crontab` for the invoking user (or the mentioned user as `root`) reading from STDIN. This is what happended in your case.

`grep` without any option will generate an error message on STDERR as usual and you are piping the STDOUT of `grep` to STDIN of `crontab` which is blank hence your `crontab` will be gone.

Comment: Some versions of `crontab` require you to use `-` as the filename to read from standard input. I assume this is because too many people blew away their crontabs with mistakes like this.

Answer (score 4):

How did he terminate the job?  Did he type C-c or C-d?  If he typed C-d, then it's equivalent to running `crontab < /dev/null` and you have replaced the user's crontab file with an empty one.  On the other hand, if you kill `crontab` with C-c, then the crontab might have been preserved, but you can easily check that by running `crontab -l`.

All this program does is edit the crontab files in `/var/spool/cron/`, so if you happen to have a backup of the file system, you can just restore the user's crontab file from there.

### update

I didn't see that there was no argument to the grep, so grep will error out and indeed the crontab file will be blown away always.

Comment: You don't need to C-c or C-d the crontab will already be gone